# Cross Compiling in c++ (as part of an cross platform application or as service)

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-libraries, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I'm trying to integrate compilation of small code segments to my application. How do I compile a piece of code for multiple platforms to a shared library (Invokable through code if possible) while introducing as little overhead as humanly possible? The biggest issue is providing all the compiling toolchains with an application.

I have looked into [conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). When I understood correctly Clang is not a thing that could be shipped with an application. As for conan I don't know yet.

Alternatively I might build a service where all needed compiling toolchains would reside and our system would call this service over network and receive a library as an answer.

The latter seems to be the most reasonable solution but I'm not sure if this should be the way to go.

What would be the best tool to use on server side linux to compile c++ code for linux, windows and OS X if possible?

Comment: Please edit down your question to a concise *technical* question.   Your first 7 paragraphs should be deleted and maybe expand on the last paragraph a little.

Comment: @xaxxon I edited the question should be more readable know.

Comment: Do you want to *link* the code or just compile it?   Linking is much harder.  Things like distcc tend to do remote compilation but local linking so you know all the files to link against for that OS are present.  clang makes the compiling for whatever super easy but it's not a linker.

Comment: @xaxxon I want to generate a library that I can load and bind dynamically with dlopen(Linux) or LoadLibrary(Windows). I'm trying to bring the compilation step to just pressing a button and having a library for each platfrom as a result. I'm am trying to stick to c++ standard library so the os related files shouldn't be an issue. It's more about the format of the shared library.

Comment: shared libraries aren't in the c++ standard, so your statement doesn't make sense.   They are an OS concept, so you have to deal with OS-related files.   C++ spec describes a conceptual (non-existent) c++ virtual machine.

Comment: @xaxxon Sure this is clear to me. I know however, which OSes I want to target and I want to make sure that a user can trivially compile his code for the 3 major OSes. Loading and using of this libraries is not a problem. All I want is to load a library that uses the standard library from my program that also uses only the standard library(or some cross platform libraries that work for the OSes of interest).

Comment: The answer to this is that cross-linking hard and that no one here can really walk you through it.  You're going to be reading a lot of different pages on how to do it -- and it's not just "per-OS" -- it's going to depend on what version of the OS as well (especially for linux).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have one library that works on several OS families, because the formats are incompatible. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats for what format is used on the target OS

You can only use a build tool that support cross compilation and set it up to build/link the correct library to generate a correct binary for the target OS, like [CMake](https://cmake.org/) / [Bazel](https://bazel.build/)